# Search a dynamoDB table attribute as a sort key

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that is defined like:

```
UUId,itemName,itemOwner
1,item1,owner1
2,item1,owner2
```

I have 2 global secondary indexes on this table
name_index -> itemName(PartitionKey)
owner_index -> itemOwner(PartitionKey), ItemName(SortKey)

I have annotate the dynamoDB Item class like this:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute
@DynameDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "name_index")
@DynameDBIndexRangeKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "owner_index")
private String itemName;


@DynamoDBAttribute
@DynameDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "owner_index")
private String itemOwner;
```

However when I attempt to query the table by the item owner it fails to return anything.

```
Item itemKey = new ItemName();
itemKey.setItemOwner("owner1");
itemKey.setItemName("item1");
DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> expr = DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>().withIndexName("owner_index").withHashKeyValues(itemKey).withConsistentRead(false);
return mapper.query(ItemKey.class, expr);
```

I then tried to change the query to set range key:

```
Item itemKey = new ItemName();
itemKey.setItemOwner("owner1");
List<AttributeValue> valueList = new LinkedList<>();
AttributeValue nameVal = new AttributeValue();
nameVal.setS("item1");
valueList.add(nameVal);
Condition con = new condition();
con.setComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ);
con.setAttributeValueList(valueList);
DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> expr = DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>().withIndexName("owner_index").withHashKeyValues(itemKey).withRangeKeyCondtion("itemName", condition).withConsistentRead(false);
return mapper.query(ItemKey.class, expr);
```

This also returns nothing. If I do a a query through the console however with `owner_index` with values `owner` and `name` it returns the correct record.

What am I doing wrong with the sort key for my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Issue:

The no data being returned was an issue of me running other test code before querying that was altering the data. After fixing the data and code, both options worked. The first query snippet however does not search by sort key, but only by the hash key column, `itemOwner` in this case and was returning all values.

### Correct query code:

```
Item itemKey = new ItemName();
itemKey.setItemOwner("owner1");
List<AttributeValue> valueList = new LinkedList<>();
AttributeValue nameVal = new AttributeValue();
nameVal.setS("item1");
valueList.add(nameVal);
Condition con = new condition();
con.setComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ);
con.setAttributeValueList(valueList);
DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> expr = DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>().withIndexName("owner_index").withHashKeyValues(itemKey).withRangeKeyCondtion("itemName", condition).withConsistentRead(false);
return mapper.query(ItemKey.class, expr);
```

### Correct Annotation:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute
@DynameDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "name_index")
@DynameDBIndexRangeKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "owner_index")
private String itemName;


@DynamoDBAttribute
@DynameDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "owner_index")
private String itemOwner
```